# View overlays the ActionBar and the NavigationBar while making scene transition animation

Tags: android-animation, material-design, android-gridview

I have a GridView in my Activity. On click of a GridView item, I'm starting **a scene transition (an animation which changes the bounds of the item's image)**.

Below is the piece of my code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DetailActivity.class);
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, view, "trantion_poster");
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

The animation works perfectly. But what happens is - if I scroll down in the GridView & click on the item which is behind the ActionBar, this is how it looks -

[image: The View overlays the ActionBar]

Similarly, if I click on the item which is behind the NavigationBar, it overlays the NavigationBar like this -

[image: The View overlays the NavigationBar]

I tried this in my App theme - `<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>`

Also, this for my GridView - `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

But nothing worked.

How can I solve this?
Any sort of help is appreciated!